# "Noch nie" vs. "nie"

Tags: time, terminology

As far as I can see, "noch nie" means "never", but "nie" also means "never".

So when to use each form? Eg

> Ich habe diesen Film nie gesehen

or

> Ich habe diesen Film noch nie gesehen

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's getting clear if you translate *noch nie* with *not until now*.

Your first sentence just states seen=yes or seen=no. You could use it in a neutral, informational situation or to express your disinterest.

The second sentence implies there's still an opportunity or will to try it. You could for instance use *noch nicht* when you're at the cinema and you discuss which movie to watch next.

Comment: I thought for the "not yet" case it would be like "ich habe diesen Film noch nicht gesehen". Is this valid as well?

Comment: @karoshi: *nicht* or *nie* - it doesn't matter, the number is always 0. You can say both ones, though *nie* puts more weight on that 0 than *nicht*.

Comment: @karoshi I would even say that "Ich habe den Film noch *nicht* gesehen." is much more common than "Ich habe den Film noch *nie* gesehen.". I think one uses "*noch nie*" more often, if it's not likey to change or you don't believe that it will: "*Das war nocht nie anders gewesen, das war schon immer so.*".

Answer (score 8):

*Nie* translates to a generic *never*, *noch nie* means *never before*, *not yet*.

> Ich habe diesen Film nie gesehen.

"I have never seen this movie."

> Ich habe diesen Film noch nie gesehen

"I haven't seen this movie ever before."